# New Space Lower-Bound Techniques for Streaming Algorithms

Tags: lower-bounds, streaming-algorithms, proof-techniques

Is communication complexity (CC) the only known approach for streaming algorithms lower bounds? Are there any other techniques, even if *conditional* lower bounds?

In general, are we satisfied with the progress achieved via CC? Or seeking alternative techniques (even if conditional) would be an interesting direction?

Answer (score 4):

A recent [result of Li, Nguyen, and Woodruff](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~hlnguyen/papers/lnw14b.pdf) shows that for any streaming algorithm in the turnstile model (where the stream consists of insertions and deletions of elements) there exists an algorithm that works by only maintaining a linear sketch and uses only slightly more space. So to prove a space lower bound in the turnstile model it is (up to some logarithmic factors) enough to prove a space lower bound for linear sketches. These can be easier to prove, for example by proving a communication lower bound in the simultaneous communication model rather than in the one-way model, or by more directly working with the linear structure of the sketch: check the paper for a lower bound on the space complexity of frequency moments proved this way.

Answer (score 3):

While not new, (and depending on what you consider to be "streaming algorithms"), a standard lower bound technique is picking a (as large as possible) set of inputs, and proving that each has to lead the algorithm to a distinct memory configuration. The implied lower bound is then the log of the number of such inputs.

For example, [Datar et al.](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu/504/1/2001-34.pdf) showed (Section 3) an $\Omega(\epsilon^{-1}\log^2 N\epsilon)$ lower bound for computing a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation for the number of ones in the last $N$ bits of a binary stream.

Comment: This is really a simple communication lower bound in disguise.